# Classes not Loading Properly?

Tags: java, classloader

I have a script on my computer that runs other scripts depending on what command I type. These tasks are frequently done and usually only need a few arguments (like updating a git repository). This is done using bash scripts, but I wanted to add more flexibility, so I'm converting it into Java.

There is a separate file that is used to 'register' these commands. I use the following syntax:

`name, alias1, alias2,... (one or more tabs) path.to.main.class`

When a command is typed is searches this file to find the correct classpath to load.

`name` is the name of the command (as well as the jar) it is used for output and for finding the appropriate jar. It then uses `path.to.main.class` to load that class. Because that class `extends` an abstract class I've made, I then cast and call a method called `onCommandRun`, self-explanatory.

Each command is exported to a jar, although most only need one class file to run. There is a command that requires three classes (although I could probably just stick them in the same class, but I don't like internal classes).

My problem is, the main class of that jar loads fine, but when I use one of the other two utility class it needs to run, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`/`ClassNotFoundxception`

And from my understanding, the JVM loads the classes it needs when it needs them, so why does it have trouble loading the other classes?

Extra: each 'command jar' is in a separate folder than the main jar controlling everything.

Extra #2: The reason for separating each command into it's own jar is because the main jar controlling everything is only going to run one command, so why register all commands (and load) all commands when only one is going to be used, and then the program exits? Plus, I wanted it to be dynamic.

Comment: Why register all commands? Because you're not saving any time by doing it your way, and dynamic loading is hard (as you're seeing). Also, why would you choose Java over Bash for this task? This seems like you're re-inventing Bash functions.  If you really want to do it this way, though, please include some relevant code.  (How you load the jars, the full stack trace and where it points, etc.)

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your main script (the one that reads the file with the mapping from name and aliases to a Java fully-qualified class name) has a line which has something like:

```
java -cp "/path/to/main.jar:/path/to/specificCommand.jar" com.example.MainClass
```

I'm guessing that the classpath (as defined by `-cp`) currently just has the jar file for your specific command. However, the jar file for the specific command doesn't automatically load in the main jar file which contains your abstract class (plus whatever other general classes you have in there). You need to make that the jar files containing any classes you need are all specified in the `-cp` argument.

I want to make a quick plug for [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) as a scripting language which gives you complete access to Java libraries (especially through it's `@Grab` annotations).